# Docker In Docker Jenkins on Ubuntu - Permission issue with docker.sock

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, jenkins

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins docker image similar to the approach described in https://getintodevops.com/blog/the-simple-way-to-run-docker-in-docker-for-ci

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install sudo
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates \ 
    curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] \ 
    https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
USER jenkins
```

And I'm starting the container like so:

```
docker run -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
    -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock customjenkins
```

However when I run a build (or exec into the container and do `docker ps`) I get the following:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket 
at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/
containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

The only way I've been able to get this to work is to `chmod 777` the `docker.sock` file, which seems wrong to me. Is there some other step I am missing or other solution I can follow?

Host OS is Ubuntu 19.04, Docker version 19.03.0-beta2, build c601560

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run the command with **sudo**:

```
sudo docker run -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
    -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock customjenkins
```

Otherwise you don't have permissions to read/write to the socket, which is completely normal and expected. Using `chmod 777` is indeed a bad idea, as it poses a security issue.

---

Besides using **sudo** there are two other suggested ways to use docker:

**1.** Add your user to the docker group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
```

Note: if the group **docker** does not exist, you can create it first:

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

**2.** Use ACL to add permission to your user to use the docker socket:

```
sudo setfacl -m user:$USER:rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

You can replace `$USER` with your username if you'd like.

Comment: Adding the ACL value for the user did the trick for me, thanks.